# error found in command prompt:could not create cakecms properly

Tags: cakephp

I am learning to creating app in Cake PHP through tutorials..I have configured cake php successfully..now while creating app named cakecms threw command prompt it gives me error that "could not create 'cakecms' properly"

please tell me where i am doing wrong?

on command prompt screen i have written a command as following

```
C:\>cd wamp\www
C:\wamp\www>cake bake cakecms

Welcome to CakePHP v2.6.3 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : www
Path: C:\wamp\www\
---------------------------------------------------------------
What is the path to the directory layout you wish to copy?
[C:\wamp\cake\lib\Cake\Console\Templates\skel] >
Skel Directory: C:\wamp\cake\lib\Cake\Console\Templates\skel
Will be copied to: cakecms
---------------------------------------------------------------
Look okay? (y/n/q)
[y] > y
Could not create 'cakecms' properly.
```

Comment: can you explain how to setup cakephp console??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
C:\wamp\www>cake bake project cakecms
```

To know more about cake bake code generate technique, read  [CakePHP’s Bake console.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html#code-generation-with-bake)

Answer (score 0):

Please first create "cakecms" directory under your wamp/www directory and after that try with "cake bake cakecms"